# Почему бездрожжевое тесто называют пресным?

Tags: этимология, значение-слов

Почему бездрожжевое тесто — пресное?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну что значит "почему?" Название такое. Очень трудно дать вообще - а в лингвистике особенно - исчерпывающий ответ на вопрос "Почему так (а не эдак)?". Так уж сложилось, что бездрожжевое тесто так назвали...

Ну а если вы о том, что обычно "пресный" понимается как несоленый и/или лишенный остроты, то тут есть некоторое объяснение.

Да, при обычном употреблении "пресный" понимается как антоним соленому или острому. 
Но есть еще одно значение, которое словари обычно не выделяют. "Пресный" - приготовленный без закваски, не бродивший.  Его можно свести к упомянутому "лишенный остроты", но в современных условиях это не так очевидно. Так что можно считать отдельным значением. ***Пресный - не квасной"***. 
Такое понимание сложилось очень давно, если не в самом еврейском оригинале Библии, то при греческом переводе уж точно. Там уже "пресный" используется именно в этом значении. А подобным образом приготовленный хлеб (маца в частности) именуется "опресноками". 
Так что еще надо сильноь обосновать, какое значение первично - "не соленый" или "не квасной".

Comment: Спасибо, интересно.